# Login not persistent throughout the app YII2

Tags: authentication, yii2, identity, access-control

I want to login a user through data received from an API.

currently, I have an `API ENDPOINT` the gives me a user token or error on user login detail submission.

By posting the token to another endpoint I get back the user Profile.

Now I need that user profile to be persistent throughout the app as long as the token is valid.

But if I call:

```
Yii::$app->user->login( $profile, 3600*24*7 );
```

the following code

```
Yii::$app->user->isGuest
```

return false only within the Auth controller . For another controller it always returns true, and I am not able to access the profile data through

```
Yii::$app->user->identity
```

Any help or maybe another better way of getting this done will be extremely appreciated.

Comment: The second parameter of `yii\web\User::login()` method is for persisting login with cookies. For api you should rather use [`yii\filters\auth\HttpBearerAuth`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-filters-auth-httpbearerauth) or [`yii\filters\auth\HttpHeaderAuth`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-filters-auth-httpheaderauth). For both of them you have to implement `findIdentityByAccessToken` method of [`yii\web\IdentityInterface`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-identityinterface#findIdentityByAccessToken()-detail)

Comment: yii\filters\auth\HttpBearerAuth or yii\filters\auth\HttpHeaderAuth seems to work only with Yii rest API. I want to Use an API developed in ASP.net for this purpose. Is there a way to use such API as Database and use the ActiveRecord class to connect to API?

Comment: It doesn't matter what API you use these filters for as long as proper headers are part of request. Bearer auth expects the `Authorization` header that looks like `Bearer ValueOfToken`. With `HttpHeaderAuth` you can specify whatever header you want as the header for token. By default `X-Api-Key` header is used. The header should hold only token value. There is no type keyword like in bearer auth case.

Comment: You should be able access the REST API from your ASP.net application. REST is an architecture that describe how API accessible through HTTP protocol should look like. It can be implemented in many different environments. You can implement the API in Yii however you want, but if you decide to follow the REST architecture then Yii already has nice support for it. [See documentation](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/rest-quick-start)